# Static Files Pythonanywhere

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, collectstatic

When I run python manage.py collectstatic in the bash console I keep getting "python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". But I can clearly see my manage.py file in my code editor, I am a beginner in django and its pretty frustrating. If anyone has any ideas what this can possibly  be, I would love your help. Thanks

[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG73E.png)

Comment: What directory are you running that command from?

Comment: my manage.py file is in my main project folder, the "django girls" folder

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `manage.py` from the directory that contains the manage.py file.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I'm a beginner and i'm suppose to run the command in the bash console of pythonanywhere. I was suppose to run the python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: In the bash console, you need to use `cd` command to change directory to the one where your `manage.py` is located. Use `pwd` command to check your current directory. It could be beneficial for you to learn basic shell commands.